# Memory usage in AnalogBinLogger of SdFat library

Tags: arduino-uno, memory-usage, flash

The AnalogBinLogger.ino file of SdFat library says the following:

> Each 512 byte data block in the file has a four byte header followed by up to 508 bytes of data. (508 values in 8-bit mode or 254 values in 10-bit mode).
>    Each block contains an integral number of samples with unused space at the end of the block.

I was wondering why only 254 values can be stored in 10-bit mode instead of (508*8 bits/ 10 bits ~ 406 values ).

1. Is this because of the memory being byte-addressable and hence does a 10-bit value take up 2 bytes?
2. If so, how will a file-reader differentiate between a 10-bit value taking 2 bytes and two 8-bit values?
3. The AnalogBinLogger.ino says:

> The logger will use SdFat's buffer plus BUFFER_BLOCK_COUNT additional buffers.

`BUFFER_BLOCK_COUNT` is 1 for the Arduino Uno since it has 2KB of SRAM. Each buffer is 512-byte long. Is **SdFat's internal buffer** also in SRAM? If I am not wrong, the libraries the program uses and the program code reside in the Flash memory, can SdFat write into a buffer in Flash memory?

Comment: yes it is because it takes 2 bytes. "10 bit mode" is the 10 bit mode of the ADC, the source of the data, not some 10 bit mode of the file

Comment: @Juraj If the ADC converts the analog values to a 10-bit binary value, why does the value take 16 bits when written to the file?

Comment: @Harini: Because you cannot store bits in a file. A file is a sequence of _bytes_.

Comment: it is only an example, not an exercise in optimization or compression

Comment: @EdgarBonet Sure, in that case, referring to the second part of my question: how does a file-reader differentiate between a 10-bit value and two 8-bit values? You can post it as an answer so that I can mark it accepted for this question.

Answer (score 1):

> how will a file-reader differentiate between a 10-bit value taking 2
>   bytes and two 8-bit values?

The file [AnalogBinLogger.h](https://github.com/greiman/SdFat/blob/master/examples/AnalogBinLogger/AnalogBinLogger.h), which comes with the example sketch you
mentioned, contains the following:

```cpp
// First block of file.
struct metadata_t {
  unsigned long  adcFrequency;     // ADC clock frequency
  unsigned long  cpuFrequency;     // CPU clock frequency
  unsigned long  sampleInterval;   // Sample interval in CPU cycles.
  unsigned long  recordEightBits;  // Size of ADC values, nonzero for 8-bits.
  unsigned long  pinCount;         // Number of analog pins in a sample.
  unsigned long  pinNumber[123];   // List of pin numbers in a sample.
};
```

Thus, the file reader just needs to be aware of the format of this first
block, and read the `recordEightBits` field in order to know whether
this is 8-bit data or not.

> Is SdFat's buffer also in SRAM?

Yes, that's the only sensible place you could have a data buffer. [It's
allocated on the stack](https://github.com/greiman/SdFat/blob/master/examples/AnalogBinLogger/AnalogBinLogger.ino#L591), only during the execution of the
`logData()` function.

Comment: Is this the 'four-byte header' mentioned in AnalogBinLogger.ino which I have quoted in my question? But clearly, this header is 24 bytes.

Comment: @Harini: No. This is the first block of the file. It's 512 bytes long, not 24. The four byte header you mention is in every block except the first one.

Comment: You're right, pardon me for not accounting for the 123 elements in `pinNumber`. It would be helpful if you can clarify the third part of the question about SRAM and Flash memory use.

Comment: Yes, the line of code highlighted in the link provided is the additional buffer SdFat uses. The sketch mentions the use of [SdFat's internal buffer](https://github.com/greiman/SdFat/blob/3b79f38cb554809a45a0ccd6d9d6752b6ad948c2/examples/AnalogBinLogger/AnalogBinLogger.ino#L92) and my question is whether this too resides in the SRAM.